# How is the image overflowing even with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: image overflow]

This is the web : https://gsemyong.github.io/faq-accordion-card/

```
.card__illustration {
  background-image: url("./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom -12rem left -48rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

.illustration__box {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20rem;
  left: -7.8rem;
  animation: box-float 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

Website creds to : gsemyong

I'm trying to learn the code of the web but I don't understand how to box is able to be outside the div even if the div has an Overflow : hidden value

Comment: I did not find any `overflow: hidden`.  Which css class has this style rule?

Comment: .card__illustration

Comment: the `position: absolute;` considers its parent to be the element which is `position: relative;`. If the relative element has overflow hidden, the image will not be shown. Any parent of absolute element, having whatever properties, will have no effect till it is not positioned relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Box image is not *overflowing*, it has its `position` attribute set to `absolute`, which means that it is outside the layout flow, if you check the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), it says:

> **Position: Absolute**
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
> This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse with other margins.

The box is positioned relative to the `div.card` element, which has a `position: relative` value. It is *outside* the bounds of the *card* because it has its `left` attribute set to a negative value, but, since **it is outside the normal document flow**, it could be anywhere on the page.

You can see that the `img.illustration__woman-online--desktop` is affected by the `overflow: hidden` and the image gets cropped, on the left side, because it uses relative positioning:

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were static.
> This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. Its effect on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.